# Outline accessibility

Tags: html, css, accessibility

can you help me to say how realized on ***Outline accessibility*** [element.eleme.io](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/installation). Because i want create div focusable and add `tabindex="0"`. But when i clicked on div in my custom component i see ugly outline style. 
I read many articles and not see good variant. Most popular article about focus-ring on Medium also has been read. 
    But maybe you have good solution without javascript. Or maybe need create semantic html?

Answer (score 0):

You can style the focus indicator using the :focus selector in CSS. No Javascript is needed to change it. You shouldn’t erase it as some people need to see it, but you can make it look nice and match your site design. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus A dotted border in the same colour as your text, which uses CSS transitions to ease in and ease out is usually nice.